# How to group by one field and average by multiple

Tags: java

With JAVA Streams, I would like to accomplish a task of grouping by one field and calculating weighted average over multiple fields.

```
 Map<String, Double> ratings = reviews
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(NoteReview::getCreatedBy,
                    Collectors.averagingDouble([here it should read: 0.5*getSkill1 + 0.2*getSkill2 and so on])));
```

How this could be achieved? My solution is to create a transient field, which calculates the value in the square brackets, is there a way to do so without a transient field?

Comment: What do you mean, "transient field"?  Why aren't you just using a lambda?

Comment: What you have written is almost exactly correct already, except it should be a -> 0.5 * a.getSkill(1) etc

Comment: You are right!:) Put this as an answer, I shall accept it.

Comment: @nomadus I can't right now as I'm on my mobile and can't format code easily. It doesn't matter - I'm just glad it helped.